# exercice: continuous semi-martingale

Tags: probability

Let $X_t=X_0+M_t+A_t$ a continuous semi-martingale.
Let $g:R->[-1,1]$ ,$C^{\infty}$ with g(x)=-1 if $x \leq 0$ and g(x)=1 if $x \geq 1$.
Let $f_n:R->R$ with $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n'(x)=g(nx)$ with $x \in R$
Show for any n, $(f_n(X_t))_t$ is a continuous semi-martingale and to give its decomposition.
How to do this exercice?

Thanks

Comment: ... what about applying Itô's formula? And please add your thoughts on the problem to the question.

Comment: I have:$f_n(X_t)=f_n(X_0)+\int_0^tg(nX_s)dM_s+\int_0^t ng'(nX_s)d<M>_s$ but i don't see the answer

Comment: Why not? What do you have to show in order to prove that it is a cts. semimartingale?

Comment: $f_n(X_0)+\int_0^t g(nX_s)dM_s$ is a martingale. I have to show $\int_0^tng'(nX_s)d<M>_s$ is a process to finite variation

Comment: $\langle M \rangle_t$ is a process of bounded variation. This implies that $$\int_0^t n g'(n X_s) \, d \langle M \rangle_s$$ is also a process of bounded variation.

Comment: ok thank you, i understand